# If there is only 1 quantity, display the name, not the number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Imagine it like a student quiz.

10 Students get a C.
6 Students get a B.
1 Student gets an A.

Rather than showing that 1 student got an A, is there a way to show the name of the student that got that result?

[image]

This is part of the result set I get. The 2 letters represent the 2 first letters of a 6 letter string corresponding to a shelf and its warehouse. If the quantity (value on the right) is 1, I want to display the full shelf value.

I am currently using a `SUBSTRING` to get the 2 letters and a `COUNT` to get the quantity

The query I am using so far may seem complicated but here it is

```
SELECT  DISTINCT SUBSTRING(location, 1, 2) AS ShelfNum,
        COUNT(location) as Quantity
FROM    warehouse_locations
WHERE   unitId_unitId = 1
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(location, 1, 2)
ORDER BY ShelfNum asc
```

If I try to add the full location on the end if the quantity is 1, I get a group-by error

Comment: Please tag the DBMS, answers may vary based on this

Comment: database management system, are you working with oracle, ms sql, mysql, something else?

Comment: im using ms sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to choose between `max(name)` and `count(location)` based on the result. You will need to convert the `count(location)` to the datatype that is returned by `max(name)`.

Sql Server example:

```
select  
    substring(location, 1, 2) as ShelfNum
  , case when count(location) = 1 then max(name)
      else cast(count(location) as varchar(32))
      end as Quantity
from warehouse_locations
where unitId_unitId = 1
group by substring(location, 1, 2)
order by ShelfNum asc
```

Also: you do not need to use `distinct` when you are using `group by`.

Comment: That worked with a few minor adjustments, thanks a lot I have been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Quantity = 1
            THEN location
            ELSE ShelfNum END as ShelfNum
       ,Quantity
FROM (
SELECT  DISTINCT SUBSTRING(location, 1, 2) AS ShelfNum,
        location,
        COUNT(location) as Quantity
FROM    warehouse_locations
WHERE   unitId_unitId = 1
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(location, 1, 2), location
)
ORDER BY ShelfNum asc
```